# asm volatile function's output for the provided code

Tags: c++, assembly

Can somebody explain be what is the following function doing:

```
 inline int atomic_exchange_and_add( int * pw, int dv )
{
 int r;
  __asm__ __volatile__
 (
    "lock\n\t"
    "xadd %1, %0":
    "=m"( *pw ), "=r"( r ): // outputs (%0, %1)
    "m"( *pw ), "1"( dv ): // inputs (%2, %3 == %1)
    "memory", "cc" // clobbers
 );
}
```

Below is its call:

```
void weak_release() // nothrow
{
    if( atomic_exchange_and_add( &weak_count_, -1 ) == 1 )
    {
        destroy();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you copied this from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp)? In which case the comments tell you what it does. And if you copied it from elsewhere, it seems someone is ripping off Boost without saying so.

Comment: no it is not a part of boost. it is some OSS i am told to work upon

Comment: An identically-named function is part of the glibc sources (albeit using a different impl), and part of the gcc/clang testsuites. In Windows/MSVC, it's what you get from the `_InterlockedExchangeAdd()` intrinsic (or `kernel32.dll` func without the underscore). While the boost sources comment on it, not everyone else does; Im unsure it's correct that boost is the "canonical source" for this code (`InterlockedExchangeAdd` is older), but a lot of places that use it attribute it to boost, agreed.